# NavLink react-router-dom not working ( working if refresh page )

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have try to use `NavLink` in `react-router-dom` but something not working. Thanks for any help.

I'm in Profile page, i click `<NavLink to="/adminboard/settings">`and it change the path to `'/adminboard/settings'` and activeClassName in Settings but i'm still in Profile page. Then i refresh page, it's going to the Settings page.

my code :

```
<AdminNav style={{ margin: '0px', padding: '0px', marginTop: '160px' }}>
    <Router style={{ margin: '0px', padding: '0px' }}>
        <Switch style={{ margin: '0px', padding: '0px' }}>
           <Route exact path="/adminboard/profile" component={AdminboardProfile} />
           <Route exact path="/adminboard/postsanpham" component={AdminPostSanPham} />
           <Route exact path="/adminboard/settings" component={AdminSetting} />
           <Route exact path="/adminboard/store" component={AdminStore} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
</AdminNav>
```

my Nav code:

```
<NavLink to="/adminboard/profile" activeClassName="active">
  <span>{faUserIcon}</span>
  <span>Profile</span>
</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/adminboard/postsanpham" activeClassName="active">
   <span>{postsanpham}</span>
   <span>Store</span>
</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/adminboard/store" activeClassName="active">
   <span>{faClipboardListIcon}</span>
   <span>Store</span>
</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/adminboard/settings" activeClassName="active">
   <span>{faToolboxIcon}</span>
   <span>Settings</span>
</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is because you did not use the exact attribute as in

```
<Route exact path='/category' component={Category}></Route>
```

exact will look for complete route ie '/adminboard/settings' if exact is not used it will stop looking further if a match is first found (it matches with 'adminboard' and will not look further)

Comment: thanks, but I have try to use exact but it's still not work

Comment: @ThanhHải Does the Router component encapsulate all your other components also please show entire code

Comment: here my code : [link](https://github.com/thanhproo1412/my-gs-client)

Comment: @ThanhHải try using 'Link' from react-router-dom it will fix the issue <Link to={`/users/${user.id}`} activeClassName="active">{user.name}</Link>

Comment: idk, it's still not working, it's working when i use 
`<NavLink to="/store" activeClassName="active">
   <span>{faClipboardListIcon}</span>
   <span>Store</span>
</NavLink>`
( i have remove /adminboard )

Comment: but i need to use the path /adminboard/...

Comment: i try to update react-router-dom to v6, it's ok for now